# JasperServer Reports returning Blank page in Yii 1

Tags: php, yii, jasper-reports

I designed a report using *iReport* tool and upload it to *JasperReports Server*  into my local server pc. In *iReport* and *JasperReports Server* the report is working perfectly but when I call the report from Yii 1 then it's not working. 
It's returning blank page instead of Data. I can not find out the issue.

Here is my yii 1 code (using YiiJasper Extension in Yii):

```
       $re = new JasperReport('/entsol/Reports/AcAccounts',
            JasperReport::FORMAT_PDF, array(
                'pAccountTile' => $pAccountTile,
                'pBranch' => $pBranch,
                'pFromDate' => $pFromDate,
                'pToDate'=>$pToDate,
            )
            );
        $re->exec();
        echo $re->reportToPDF(); //All pages
```

by using the above code I got blank page instead of data.

How do I get my issue ?

Comment: Don't know nothing about this extension, but empty report normally is empty or no datasource, are you passing a datasource or the connection?

Comment: @PetterFriberg :: Yes I added datasource in JasperServer while uploading jrxml file.

Comment: Are you using yii-jasper extension?  Make sure to have JasperServer  <= 5.5.x and php <= 5.3.x or php >= 5.5.x

Comment: @AlejandroQuiroz : I am using YiiJasper extension. JasperReport server 5.5.0 and Yii-1

Answer (score 0):

To use [yii-jasper extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiijasper/) you need JasperServer <= 5.5.x, PHP <= 5.3 or PHP >= 5.4.9 and Yii >= 1.14

Make sure to have all report parameters: same number in both (report and Yii call), correct/same order,proper values. For values, take care with [Java datatypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) in IReports (`Integer, BigInteger, Character, String, Date`, etc) and their equivalence with PHP values. Also parameter names must be equal on both (exact name, with upper and lower case).

JasperServer log file can give you some feedback about existing problems running the report. Find it in JasperServer install directory (`/your-jasperserver-install-path/apache-tomcat/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/logs`).

If persist, try creating data source directly in jasperserver and uploading again the report with option "`data source from repository`" instead any other kind of data source. To create data source in repository, log in JasperServer, find `Data sources` folder, right click and create the datasource.